# Trato de demostrar en un array que un valor es pico ( es mayor del numero a su derecha y a su izquierda) python [on hold]

Tags: python, array, árboles-binarios

Estoy aprendiendo a usar arboles binarios, el problema consiste en que tengo un error básico que no se como resolver, soy nuevo en Python:

```
print('ingresa el rango del array:')
rango=int(input())
array=[]

for i in range(rango):
    print ('ingresa el numero de la casilla', i+1,':')
    num=int(input())
    array.append(num)

mitad = rango/ 2

if (array[mitad]<array[mitad-1]):
    for i in range([0],range(mitad-1)):           
        if(array[i-1]== None and array[i+1]<array[i]):
            print (i,'es pico')
        elif(array[i-1]<array[i] and array[i+1]<array[i]):
            print (i,'es pico')
        elif(array[i+1]== None and array[i-1]<array[i]):
            print (i,'es pico')
        else:
            print('no hay pico')

elif (array[mitad]<array[mitad+1]):
    for i in range([0],range(mitad-1)):
        if(array[i-1]== None and array[i+1]<array[i]):
            print (i,'es pico')
        elif(array[i-1]<array[i] and array[i+1]<array[i]):
            print (i,'es pico')
        elif(array[i+1]== None and array[i-1]<array[i]):
            print (i,'es pico')
        else:
            print('no hay pico')
else:
    print(array[mitad],'es pico')
```

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 4, in 
    rango=int(input())
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ Es el primer error

Comment: Hola Jose, nos ayudaría si nos dices qué problema da tu código, así nos ahorras tener que ejecutarlo y ver si con la respuesta que te da tu ejecución encontramos algo.

Comment: ¿por qué tu pregunta tiene en el título la frase `[on hold]`?

Comment: TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not float, este es el error que me arroja, supongo porque al tomar el rango y dividirlo a la mitad me puede arrojar un float, pero no se como hacer que tome un integer o redondee la cifra. El on hold, no tengo ni idea, creía que lo ponía stack automáticamente.

Answer (score 0):

según lo que se de python, en

```
    if (array[mitad]<array[mitad-1]): #Sobran los parentesis
```

y en

```
    elif (array[mitad]<array[mitad+1]): #Aca tambien sobran
```

el codigo correcto seria, segun lo que sé:

```
    if array[mitad]<array[mitad-1]: #No tiene parentesis
    elif array[mitad]<array[mitad+1]: #Aca tampoco hay parentesis
```

En las secuencias lógicas, el código no se escribe entre parentesis()
Espero que te sea útil

Edicion: Me acaban de decir que el parentesis es opcional

Comment: el parentesis es opcional, puede tenerlo o no.

Comment: Gracias. no lo sabia

Comment: Te recomiendo siempre verificar antes de responder, este tipo de respuestas puede causar confusión a otros usuarios

Comment: Gracias. solo me basaba en lo que sabia